# Run mounts on CentOS startup in a WSL container

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

- I have a bunch of bind mounts that I want created in a CentOS contained in WSL that can be created running `bind --mount` commands
- I would like to run a bunch of generic commands on CentOS init for that matter

How do I set up a script to be run when the container is initialized, to manage mounts and other static config?

Clarification: I do not want to mount Windows local paths inside the container, but container paths (i.e. `mount --bind /root/x /root/y`)

Update: for the mount part, this worked:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config : Create `/etc/wsl.conf` with

```
[automount]
mountFsTab = true
```

And created `/etc/fstab` with

```
/source1 /target1 none bind
...
```

Still looking for an answer to the second part, running a script when the container is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For adding internal bind mounts to the WSL container:

   - Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config
   - Create `/etc/wsl.conf` inside the WSL container with:

     ```
     [automount]
     mountFsTab = true
     ```
   - Create `/etc/fstab` with:

     ```
     /source1 /target1 none bind
     ...
     ```
2. For running command(s) at WSL startup (**since build 21286**):

   - Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-21286
   - Create or add to `/etc/wsl.conf`:

     ```
     [boot]
     command=...
     ```